# How to add Nested Ordered Dictionary in IOS Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a sample Nested dictionary like:

```
 var sampleDictionary = ["section1": [["question1","notes1"],["question2","notes2"],["question2","notes2"],["question3","notes3"]],"section2": [["questionS2Q1","notesS2N1"],["questionS2Q2","notesS2N2"],["questionS3Q3","notesS2Q3"],["question3","notes3"]]]
```

I want to create a new list which will look like this dictionary by using a loop.

After performing a nested loop I should be able to append the values which will result like this:

```
Loop_Content_append = ["Section1": [["question1","notes1"],["question2","notes2"],["question3","notes3"]]]
```

//[Key1 : [[Array],[Array]],key2:[[Array],[Array]]]

So My Key is Section1 and Value is an array of Dictionary.

But I am not able to define it as empty or append inside loop.

How can I implement this ?
Please help.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Your "result" is a dictionary that contains a string key and an array of string arrays as the value.  Also, dictionaries are unordered.  Did you want your result to be `[String:[String:String]]` ? i.e. `String` key with a value that is an array of dictionaries with `String` keys and values?  How does the first data in the first dictionary relate to that in the second?

Comment: *"I have a sample ordered dictionary"* - no, you have an *unordered* dictionary since dictionaries have no order.

Comment: @Paulw11 Iam sorry if my question is not clear.. 
Exactly I want my result to be [String : [[String,String],[String,String]]]
That is , [Key1 : [[Array],[Array]],key2:[[Array],[Array]]]
One key will return values as array.

Comment: But how is that different to the dictionary you are starting with? It is a `[String:[[String]]`

Comment: @Paulw11 
[Key1 : [[Array],[Array]],key2:[[Array],[Array]]] This is the format I want it to be..
Here is where I was stuck..! :/

How to append data to it?

Comment: Append data to what? The dictionary or one of the arrays in the dictionary?

Comment: Exactly, do you want to append data to one of the arrays associated with an existing key?  Or do you want to add a new key with a new array?

Comment: @Paulw11 New key with a new array..

Comment: `myDictionary[newKey] = newArray` ?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have doubt:
Initially there should not be any data in dictionary..
Then when loop executes, it should create a key and append an array.
again on next iteration it will append next key and next array..
so finally I'll get a dictionary like names = [key1:[[array1],[array2]],key2:[[array1],[array2]]]
let me know if I am not clear...pls

Comment: No, you are clear.  I don't understand your problem.  `var dictionary = [String:[String]]()   for some loop { dictionary[newKey] = newArray} `

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to show the code you have tried and explain your specific problem or error

Comment: @Paulw11 I'll try and let you know...
Thanks... :)

Comment: I think you would be better off creating a struct/class to store this data.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks... It worked.. If you can update it as answer i'll mark it as right answer.. !